# Rubay Rails exiting on startup - Segmentation fault

Tags: ruby-on-rails, runtime-error

I have inherited a rails application that i try to run on a new linux server. But when I try to start the rails server, it exits with a segmentation fault.

linux : DEBIAN 10

rvm : 1.29.12

gem : 3.2.32

ruby : 3.0.3p157 (2021-11-24 revision 3fb7d2cadc) [x86_64-linux]

rails : 3.2.22

When I launch rails -v, I have a ton of warnings like this one:

/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/pathname.rb:20: warning: already initialized constant Pathname::TO_PATH

And when I launch the rails server I have this error:

/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.3@rails_3.0.3/gems/railties-3.2.22/lib/rails/engine.rb:643: [BUG] Segmentation fault at 0x0000000000000008

Regarding the warning messages that I had running "rails -v", I could remove them with the two following commands: "bundle clean --force" and "bundle update". After this I had this error: "cannot load such file : webrick" and I solved it with "bundle add webrick", but now when I try to start rails server I have this new error:

/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.3@rails_3.0.3/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:408:in `block (2 levels) in replace_gem': can't activate sqlite3 (~> 1.3.5), already activated sqlite3-1.6.8-x86_64-linux. Make sure all dependencies are added to Gemfile. (Gem::LoadError)

Comment: Try `bundle exec rails -v`

Comment: Rails 3 with Ruby 3 is never going to work. You are going to need to update Rails and in the mean time downgrade ruby until you can get a to a point where you can upgrade again. Rails 3.2.22 released 2015-06-16 (EOL June of 2016), ruby 3.0.3 released 2021-11-24. These were never intended to play nice together.

Comment: Indeed, the server I inherited my application from was in ruby 1.9.2 but I get errors installing ruby 1.9.2 with rvm on my debian 10, what can I do?